# Why do powershell functions have to be named using 'approved verbs'?

Tags: powershell

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/ps101/09-functions?view=powershell-7.2#naming) states...

> When naming your functions in PowerShell, use a Pascal case name with
> an approved verb and a singular noun.[...] In PowerShell, there's a specific list of approved verbs that can be
> obtained by running `Get-Verb`.

...followed by a list of approved verbs.

Why such rule?

Comment: They don't "have" to be. You honestly can name them whatever you like. It's meant for easy discoverability; with the fact that it makes sense. Continuing with the naming schemes not only helps you, but future readers as well. Take for account `Get-Process`, what would you name it? What you will see is, helper functions named something that shouldn't and won't be exposed to users using your functions and/or, your modules.

Comment: In other/simpler terms: It's PowerShell's syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using approved verbs in PowerShell function and cmdlet names is a best practice that helps to promote consistency, predictability, discoverability, and automation of PowerShell code.

It's strongly encouraged because it helps to promote consistency and predictability across PowerShell code. PowerShell uses a verb-noun pair for the names of cmdlets and functions, and the recommended naming convention is to start the function name with an approved verb and then use a hyphen (-) to separate the verb from the noun. The approved verb gives an idea of what the function does, and this helps to make code easier to understand and use.

Using approved verbs also helps to ensure that the code is discoverable and easier to automate since PowerShell workflows can be automated based solely on the names of cmdlets and functions.

To find a list of approved verbs, you can use the Get-Verb cmdlet.

You may be interested in visiting Approved Verbs for PowerShell Commands here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands